# Why did the 2020 annual survey ask your age, when that can also be derived from two earlier questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, survey-2020

In the [current annual survey](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_eL0mFVwuo7KWeXP), in one of the questions, it asks for your age in an optional question right before asking your gender/race/sexuality.

> [image]

However, shortly before that, it asks when you first started coding, and how long you've been coding - and by simply adding those two numbers together, you can derive the user's age, making the question explicitly asking for age redundant?

> [image]

So, why ask the question at all? Is it just to try to avoid rounding errors?

Comment: I wish my age was the sum of those two numbers. But it isn't. I've written my first line of code back when I was 10 or so. Over the years I did write more but it wasn't until I started my compsci degree in uni that I officially consider myself actually *coding*. So were you to sum 10 + <years since I started uni> you'd get a 9 year gap. And I've at least been coding for the duration - if I had, say, taken a break, then the gap would expand to that.

Answer (score 16):

Some people wrote their first line of code and didn’t start regularly programming until much later.

Some people stop coding and then pick it back up again.

In these cases, the age they wrote their first line of code plus the number of years they have been coding will not equal their age.

Comment: That's true. Wrote my first line of code on an experimental system long before computers were available for all and long before I chose it as career. Would be nice if my age would equal the one calculated from that :D

Comment: If I was to use the sum of those numbers, I'd be 19. I wish I was 19 again...

Answer (score 9):

All three questions are optional. Users may opt to skip any of the three questions if they do not wish to answer a particular age question, or all of them.